# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, filter

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from '../../shared';
import {array} from 'prop-types';
import { EmployeeTable } from '../employeeTable/EmployeeTable';
import './HeaderSearch.scss';

export class HeaderSearch extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        employees: array
    }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchValue: null
        };
    }

    _updateSearchValue (value) {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: value
        });
    }

    render () {
        const employees = this.props.employees;
        let filteredEmployees = employees.filter(
                (employee) => {
                    return employee.name.indexOf(this.state.searchValue) !== -1;
                }
            );
        return (
            <div className='header_search'>
                <ul>
                    {filteredEmployees.map((employee) => {
                        return <EmployeeTable
                            employees={employee}
                            key={employee.id}
                            />;
                    })}
                </ul>
                <TextInput
                    label='Search for people'
                    value={this.state.searchValue}
                    onChange={(e) => this._updateSearchValue(e.target.value)}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default HeaderSearch;
```

I'm a newbie at ReactJS so I'm getting stuck on this problem. I realize this question has been asked and I looked through them all but still couldn't find a solution as to why I'm getting this error. I want to filter the array `employees` according to the `searchValue` and display the update `Employee Table`.

Comment: Well like all other questions with this error, it means you are trying to use something on a variable that is undefined. Meaning a variable doesn't hold what you think it does. Make sure `employees` is actually an array (eg console.log it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add default value for `HeaderSearch`

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from '../../shared';
import {array} from 'prop-types';
import { EmployeeTable } from '../employeeTable/EmployeeTable';
import './HeaderSearch.scss';

export class HeaderSearch extends PureComponent {

    static defaultProps = { // <-- DEFAULT PROPS
        employees: []       // undefined gets converted to array,render won't trigger error
    }

    static propTypes = {
        employees: array
    }

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchValue: null
        };
    }

    _updateSearchValue (value) {
        this.setState({
            searchValue: value
        });
    }

    render () {
        // omitted
    }
}
export default HeaderSearch;
```

Error triggers when `employees` prop is not provided, or null or undefined, when you provide default value of empty Array, the `Array.filter` won't throw error, because default value of `employees` is an instance of Array

Answer (score 2):

As the error message tells you, problem is that your constant `employees` is undefined. The problem will be in a place where you are rendering `HeaderSearch` component. Most likely you are not passing it the props you think you are. Try to render`<HeaderSearch employees={[]} />`. Does it work? What does `console.log(this.props)` show you? Can you see key `employees` there?

If you need more assistance please post the code where you are actually rendering `HeaderSearch` component.

Comment: This is the entire code for the HeaderSearch. I used console.log for employees and it shows that it's undefined. Where should i define the array in this code?

Comment: You shouldn't define the array in `HeaderSearch` code. Your code is expecting `employees` to be given as a property when you use the component. Something like `<HeaderSearch employees={<any-array-of-employees>} />. This will make empoyees available in `this.props.employees`.

Comment: Also as @Medet Tleukabiluly mentions in his answer you can use `defaultProps` to set default value.